# Is this map of domains a Jordan homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\phi\colon D\to D'$ be a map of division rings, such that $\phi$ is a 
homomorphism of the additive groups, respects unity, and if $a\neq 0$, $\phi(a)\neq 0$, and $\phi(a)^{-1}=\phi(a^{-1})$. It's a theorem of L.K. Hua that $\phi$ is either a homomorphism of anti-homomorphism, but I'm struggling to prove it.

It's a result of Jacobson and Rickart that any Jordan homomorphism of a ring into a 
domain is either a homomorphism or an anti-homomorphism ([Theorem 2 of this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1950-069-00/S0002-9947-1950-0038335-X/S0002-9947-1950-0038335-X.pdf)) so I think it's sufficient to 
show $\phi$ is a Jordan homomorphism, that is, $\phi(aba)=\phi(a)\phi(b)\phi(a)$ for 
all $a,b\in D$, as the other two properties of a Jordan homomorphism are already assumed.

I was able to derive Hua's identity that if $a,b,ab-1$ are invertible elements of a 
ring, then 
$$
((a-b^{-1})^{-1}-a^{-1})^{-1}=aba-a.
$$
Now $\phi(aba)=\phi(a)\phi(b)\phi(a)$ holds if $a,b=0$, or if $ab-1=0$, so I'm only 
trying to verify for the other case where $a,b,ab-1$ are all units. Applying $\phi$ to 
$aba$ and using the above identity, I get something bad 
$$
((\phi(a)-\phi(b)^{-1})^{-1}-\phi(a)^{-1})^{-1}+\phi(a).
$$
What's the correct way to tell that $\phi$ is a homomorphism or anti-homomorphism? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically done.  Just show your work more clearly, and the answer is clear.

$$
aba = ((a-b^{-1})^{-1}-a^{-1})^{-1} + a
$$

$$
\phi(aba) \stackrel{1}{=} ((\phi(a)-\phi(b)^{-1})^{-1}-\phi(a)^{-1})^{-1}+\phi(a) 
\stackrel{2}{=} \phi(a)\phi(b)\phi(a).
$$

The first equality applies $\phi$ to Hua's identity, using that it respects addition, subtraction, and inverses. The second equality uses Hua's identity with $A=\phi(a)$ and $B=\phi(b)$.